# Need some assistance with my apache2 site config file

Tags: php, apache2

I'm trying to get apache2 to point to a PHP based application (word press in this case but the config needs to be generic enough to work for any php application).
and it either displays some basic HTML file access page or errors with "You don't have permission". I don't really know apache and I don't know PHP at all. Here's my current site_config file as it stands(with retractions replaced with ):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin <app_user>@localhost
        ServerName amazonaws.com/<app_name>
        ServerAlias *.amazonaws.com/<app_name>
        DocumentRoot /home/<app_user>/<app_location>/staging/current
        <Directory /home/<app_user>/<app_location>/staging/current >
                AllowOverride All
                Options -Indexes
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        LogLevel error

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I would also like to make it so you can have multiple websites on the same box but I'm not sure how to change the `VirtualHost` arg `*:80` to account for that, I just get loads of ignoring errors.

I also have the following line in my apache2.conf:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Folder permissions are set to `0755` for all files & folders in the project directory

output of `apache2 -v`:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

P.s. I know nothing about PHP and very little about apache2 so for this, speak to me as a total noob.

Comment: What is the apache version? The syntax you use for some parts (`Order allow,deny [...] Allow from all`) has changed and is obsolete since 2.4.

Comment: added version to op, I changed the `Order allow` lines to `Require all granted` and now it's displaying a PHP wordpress error, which Is an improvement, so thanks.

Comment: You don't change the `<VirtualHost *:80>` line.  You create other configurations with different ServerName attributes.

Comment: mod_macro can be of help for templating your configurations.  But there are also other tricks see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: how do I make it so typing `/<app_name>` will point to the correct directory? also apache seems to ignore my `<Directory>` block because when I remove the `DocumentRoot` directive it stops showing the PHP error and just displays directory page of the default directory.

Comment: As a noob, I'd firstly concentrate on getting a html file to work, then a primitive php one (hello world).  Then perhaps Wordpress, and then... multiple configurations.

Comment: In answer to your app_name question, perhaps: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Comment: @Progrock I'm not actually building the app, just trying to deploy it and build it in a generic way to work with all php apps, a php index file already exists so I can just point to that.

Answer (score 0):

To solve The first problem I had to change the following lines:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to:

```
Require all granted
```

this finally allowed apache to allow users access to the folders, the second thing was to add an alias:

```
Alias /<app_name> "/home/<app_user>/<app_location>/staging/current"
```

and it started working as expected so now my site config looks like:

```
Alias /<app_name>"/home/<app_user>/<app_name>/<app_environment>/current"
<Directory "/<app_name>"/home/<app_user>/<app_name>/<app_environment>/current">
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/<app_name>"/home/<app_user>/<app_name>/<app_environment>/current"
        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/<app_name>.error_log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/<app_name>.access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```